# How to create Stacked Scatter Plot in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, scatter-plot, stacked

I want to be able to create Stacked Scatter plot. So that same `Y-axis` and `X-axis` would be required. Each scatter plot should be at vertical distance from each other. Also all scatter plots should have same `Y-axis` and  I want them to have same y-labels on each interval.

I have tried Subplot but that doesn't give what I want. Anybody have any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use some vertical separation?

```
x  = rand(1,100); %// example x axis data
y1 = rand(1,100); %// example y axis data 1
y2 = rand(1,100); %// example y axis data 2
y3 = rand(1,100); %// example y axis data 3
sep = 2; %// vertical separation

hold all
plot(x, y1, '.')
plot(x, sep+y2, '.')
plot(x, 2*sep+y3, '.')
```

[image]

Or better, use `subplot`:

```
subplot(3,1,1)
plot(x, y1, 'r.')
subplot(3,1,2)
plot(x, y2, 'g.')
subplot(3,1,3)
plot(x, y3, 'b.')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanx man !! this helps a lot. But is there a way to re-label the Yaxis for each y1,y2 and y3. Because y1,y2 and y3 have same range

Comment: You can do that, but it's tricky. Why not just three subplots vertically stacked?

Comment: What do u mean by that?

Comment: @Spandy See updated answer, second part